# jest mocking and setting up default behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

There is a function I need to unit test:

```
const readiness = require("./readiness");

function stopProcessNewRequests(){
    readiness.setNotReady();
}
```

Here is my **"readiness"** file:

```
const state = require("./state");
const hooks = require("./hooks");

function setReady(){
    state.ready = true;
    hooks.notifyHook(state.ready);
}

function setNotReady(){
    state.ready = false;
    hooks.notifyHook(state.ready);
}

module.exports = {
    setReady, setNotReady
};
```

and finally, the **state.js** file:

```
exports.ready = false;

exports.pendingRequests = {};

exports.changeStatusHooks = [];

exports.requestsInProcessNum = 0;

exports.authClient = null;
exports.webOperationsClient = null;
exports.webQueryClient = null;
```

As you can see, there are multiple chained imports, how do I mock them? I need my state file to be of certain values in order to check if it actually changes.
Here's what I have, but **state** does not seem to change, and the test fails.

```
describe('Testing processing new requests:', ()=> {
        test('should stop processing new requests:', ()=> {
            // jest.mock('../lib/grpc/readiness',);
            jest.mock('../lib/grpc/state');

            const state = require("../lib/grpc/state");
            const { stopProcessNewRequests } = require('../lib/grpc/requestsManager');

            state.ready = true;

            stopProcessNewRequests();

            expect(state.ready).toBeFalsy();
        })
    })
```

Comment: the problem is that readiness file imports state, and while testing mutates the original one, not the one I am requiring in my test.

Answer (score 1):

It is best not to test across modules. Which means for testing `requestsManager` module, you should mock `readiness` module, not indirectly module `state` and `hooks`. Besides, `jest.mock` should **NOT** be used in function scope, it should be used in module scope.

E.g.

`readiness.js`:

```js
const state = require('./state');
const hooks = require('./hooks');

function setReady() {
  state.ready = true;
  hooks.notifyHook(state.ready);
}

function setNotReady() {
  state.ready = false;
  hooks.notifyHook(state.ready);
}

module.exports = {
  setReady,
  setNotReady,
};
```

`hooks.js`:

```js
function notifyHook() {}

module.exports = { notifyHook };
```

`requestsManager.js`:

```js
const readiness = require('./readiness');

function stopProcessNewRequests() {
  readiness.setNotReady();
}

module.exports = { stopProcessNewRequests };
```

`state.js`:

```js
exports.ready = false;

exports.pendingRequests = {};

exports.changeStatusHooks = [];

exports.requestsInProcessNum = 0;

exports.authClient = null;
exports.webOperationsClient = null;
exports.webQueryClient = null;
```

Below are test files:

`requestsManager.test.js`:

```js
const { stopProcessNewRequests } = require('./requestsManager');
const readiness = require('./readiness');

describe('62057531', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const setNotReadyMock = jest.spyOn(readiness, 'setNotReady').mockReturnValueOnce();
    stopProcessNewRequests();
    expect(setNotReadyMock).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

`readiness.test.js`:

```js
const { setNotReady, setReady } = require('./readiness');
const hooks = require('./hooks');
const state = require('./state');

describe('62057531', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should set state to not ready', () => {
    jest.spyOn(hooks, 'notifyHook').mockReturnValueOnce();
    setNotReady();
    expect(hooks.notifyHook).toBeCalledWith(false);
    expect(state.ready).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('should set state to ready', () => {
    jest.spyOn(hooks, 'notifyHook').mockReturnValueOnce();
    setReady();
    expect(hooks.notifyHook).toBeCalledWith(true);
    expect(state.ready).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/62057531/requestsManager.test.js (14.294s)
  62057531
    ✓ should pass (6ms)

 PASS  stackoverflow/62057531/readiness.test.js
  62057531
    ✓ should set state to not ready (5ms)
    ✓ should set state to ready (1ms)

--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files           |     100 |      100 |      75 |     100 |                   
 hooks.js           |     100 |      100 |       0 |     100 |                   
 readiness.js       |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 requestsManager.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 state.js           |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        17.288s, estimated 21s
```